# PL/SQL TRIGGER with RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR

Tags: plsql, triggers

I am trying to code a trigger with PL/SQL, where I want to show different messages when an error happens. The problem is when It should show more than one message.
That is my code

```
create or replace trigger Restrictionns
BEFORE INSERT ON numbers FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE 
    v_message varchar2(500);
    v_error boolean;
    v_type number;
    
BEGIN
    v_message := '';
    v_error := false;
    v_type := -20000;
    
    IF LENGTH(:new.number) > 6 THEN
        v_message := v_message || '{The length number can't be bigger than 6}';
        v_error := true;
        v_type := -20001;
    END IF;
    IF :new.number > 9 or :new.number< 0 THEN
        v_message := v_message || '{The number must be beetween 0 and 9}';                                          
        v_error := true;
         v_type := -20002;
    END IF;
    IF :new.number < 0 THEN
        v_message := v_message || '{The number can't be negative)}';
        v_error := true;
         v_type := -20003;
    END IF;
    
    IF v_error = true THEN
         RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(v_type,v_message) 
    END IF;
    
END;
/
```

For example if INSERT a negative number it should show two messages, the error -20002 and -20003... but it only shows the last one. What is the way to show all error messages when they happens?

Comment: I don't think you can do that. RAISE raises **one** error, but text can cover one (or more) cases - just as your code does, by concatenating all messages.

Comment: Do you think that I could insert the errors into a rowtype with a loop and then show all of them?

Comment: Not with the RAISE, as far as I can tell. You could (with a DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE), but only some tools will be able to display that (e.g. SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, TOAD - but only if serveroutput is enabled). As no end-user will ever use that, and front-end application (e.g. Oracle Apex, Forms, ...) can't display it, then - no, I don't think you can do it.